# Moving a line and a bookmark using visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-word, bookmarks

Trying to use Visual Basic to delete a line if a text box is not used with a corresponding bookmark in Word. The user will use click a button and will evaluate if a text box has been used.

For example if say TITLEWARNO was not used via text box it will look like this:

> ORDNUM
>
> OPERATIONORDERWIT

I need it to do this:

> ORDNUM
> OPERATIONORDERWIT

I've tried \LINE and trim commands. I have been really stuck on this for the last day and googled different variation of this that's not working.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ORDNUM As Range
    Set ORDNUM = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ORDNUM").Range
    ORDNUM.Text = Me.ORDNUM.Value
    
    Dim TITLEWARNO As Range
    Set TITLEWARNO = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TITLEWARNO").Range
    TITLEWARNO.Text = Me.TITLEWARNO.Value
    
    Dim OPERATIONORDERWIT As Range
    Set OPERATIONORDERWIT = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("OPERATIONORDERWIT").Range
    OPERATIONORDERWIT.Text = Me.OPERATIONORDERWIT.Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim ORDNUM As Range
  Set ORDNUM = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ORDNUM").Range
  If Me.ORDNUM.Value = vbNullString Then
    ORDNUM.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ORDNUM").Delete
  Else
    ORDNUM.Text = Me.ORDNUM.Value
  End If
    
  Dim TITLEWARNO As Range
  Set TITLEWARNO = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TITLEWARNO").Range
  If Me.TITLEWARNO.Value = vbNullString Then
    TITLEWARNO.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TITLEWARNO").Delete
  Else
    TITLEWARNO.Text = Me.TITLEWARNO.Value
  End If
    
  Dim OPERATIONORDERWIT As Range
  Set OPERATIONORDERWIT = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("OPERATIONORDERWIT").Range
  If Me.OPERATIONORDERWIT.Value = vbNullString Then
    OPERATIONORDERWIT.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("OPERATIONORDERWIT").Delete
  Else
    OPERATIONORDERWIT.Text = Me.OPERATIONORDERWIT.Value
  End If
```

A simpler way would be to have a single bookmark and build up the text string adding carriage returns (vbCr) as needed.

Comment: Thank you! For some weird reason, "ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("OPERATIONORDERWIT").Delete" was not required to get what I needed. it made sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Each line will end with a return. Make sure the bookmark includes that return. Then, in place of ORDNUM.Text = Me.ORDNUM.Value, use something like this:

```
If Me.ORDNUM.Value = vbCr Then
  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ORDNUM").Range.Text.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: Very helpful on another project, Thank you!